# How take values of params a URL in Django and give a Form

Tags: python, django, forms, post, get

`models.py`

```
class Prueba(models.Model): #collection name

    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.cantidad)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "home_app"

urlpatterns = [

path(
        'confirmar_viaje/',
        views.SampleView.as_view(), 
        name='userviajes',
    ),
]
```

`View.py`

```
class SampleView(CreateView):
    model=Prueba
    template_name='testpag.html'
    form_class=TestForm
    success_url = '/'

   def init_page(request):
        print(request.GET)
        pasajeros = self.request.form['pasajeros']
        print(pasajeros)
```

`forms.py`

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Prueba
        fields=['cantidad']
```

I use a DetailView, inside html have a form(html).
The result is /test/?pasajeros=99

I want to take from de url params. pasajeros=99 and fill a textfield from form.

The code dont have errors but i need to recuperate the param or params.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

in your form put for exmple in code html

```
<a href = "{% url 'home_app:userviajes'%}"> link to your forms </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is code call the CreateView than i want fill

```
<form action="/confirmar_viaje/" method="get">
              <p>name: <input type="text" name="fullname" size="40" value={{user.username}} disabled></p>
   <p>Numeber: <input type="number" name="pasajeros" ></p>
              <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </p>

          </form>
```

Why I do this, it si because this part the code it is inside of DetailView, and no its posible have two views point to one adress, so my solution its send datas via GET, and the other View catchs it the params from de URL and fill automatic my filds, so this way i have two Views with his own url.

It is the code than recive the url

```
<div>
      <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```